# Plotting data at high frequency using matplotlib:animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to write a script that will accomplish a few different things:

1) Read data from a text file that keeps being filled up by sensor data.

2) Filter this data.

3) Plot the unfiltered data.

At the moment, my script works fine for 1) and 2), but I can't get the plot to work. I think that this is complicated by the very high sampling rate I have on the sensor, 5376 Hz.

At the moment, my script polls the text file each 0.1 ms to see if a new line has been written into the document with this code:

```
# Function that continually looks at thefile.
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2) # Look at the last line in the file
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline() # line is now equal to the last line in thefile
        if not line: # If the last line in the file was empty, this will be true,
            time.sleep(0.0001)   #  and the function will sleep for 0.1 ms before continuing
            continue
        yield line # If the last line was not empty, it will be yielded
```

I then have my main script that analyses the data:

```
import time
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pylab as pl

# Opening text file in subdirectory
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #<-- absolute dir the script is in
rel_path = "python_data.txt"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

# Vectors for storing unfiltered data in
xar = []
yar = []
zar = []

pl.ion()                              # Interaction on
x = np.arange(0,10)                   # x-array
pl.line, = plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))      # Initiate line

logfile = open(abs_file_path,"r")     # Open text file
loglines = follow(logfile)            # Look for changes in text file
for line in loglines:                 # For each new line in text file
    try:
        x,y,z = line.split(' \t ')    # Split up x-, y- and z- data into different arrays.
        xar.append(int(x))
        yar.append(int(y))
        zar.append(int(z))

        line.set_ydata(int(x))       # Update the line
        pl.draw()                    # Redraw the canvas

    except:
        pass

    # I then perform the filtering of xar, yar and zar when they have reached a certain length, and reset them after filtering is done with xar = [], yar = [], zar = [].
```

The method for plotting the data I have implemented is the one specified here: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Animations.html

However, it is not working, as soon as I execute my script a figure is created, but is completely frozen, and nothing happens when I start collecting data in the text file. So I have a few questions:

1) Have I implemented the method correctly?

2) Am I calling line.set_ydata(int(x)) and pl.draw() to often, and that's why it crashes?

3) I don't really understand what happends when I create a line with pl.line, = plt.plot(x,np.sin(x)), and then update the y-element with line.set_ydata(int(x)). Does it matter what I write in the y-position of pl.line, = plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))?

4) Should I be using a completely different method if I want to update my plot with a frequency of 5376 Hz?

Comment: Wow that doc you link to is 12 years old. In any case better use the animation classes, like `FuncAnimation` to produce your animations. The matplotlib page itself has some examples of those.

Comment: Ah, didnt see that! I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391280/most-lightweight-way-to-plot-streaming-data-in-python#14393608) and ended up with attempting that solution, but I'll look into FuncAnimation, thanks!